# ¿Por que la api audio de VK, no lista nada?

Tags: php, oauth, oauth2

Por que la api audio de VK, no me muestra la lista de cansines.

Mostrar una lista de canciones con la api audio de VK, pero solo me da una con un link que dice audio api unavailable.

Esto es lo que me imprime:

```
{"response":
[1,{
"aid": 1,
"owner_id": 100,
"artist": "Аудио доступно на vk.com",
"title": "и в официальных приложениях ВКонтакте",
"duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3"
}
]
}
```

Aquí esta el ejemplo de lo que estoy implementando [VK API](https://github.com/vladkens/VK/)

Comment: ¿Cómo haces la petición?

Comment: Mediante ajax y mediante la función curl de PHP, hago una combinación de hambos métodos y me da el mismo resultado.

Comment: Pero podrías ponerlo en la pregunta? Si nos das solo la respuesta, no podremos saber de donde viene el error

Comment: No es necesario que ponga el código, pues en este repositorio github.com/vladkens/VK/ esta el ejemplo de lo que estoy implementando.

Comment: Puse el link completo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La API de audio ha sido descontinuada para aplicaciones de terceros. Solo aplicaciones autorizadas por ellos pueden usarla. Más información en https://vk.com/dev/audio